# How to formal prove |set 1| is less than or equal to |set 2| + |set 3|

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I could prove |set 1| $\le$ |set 2|by defining a function $f$ such that $f$ is a **one-to-one** function

Suppose

X = {1, 2, 3} and Y = {D, B, C, A}

or

X = {1, 2, 3, 4} and Y = {D, B, C, A}

and there is a function $f$ such that:

[image: An injective non-surjective function]

or

[image: An injective surjective function]

Then we have just proved |X| $\le$ |Y|. My question is, can we prove, let's say, |X| $\le$ |Y| + |Z| by defining a **one-to-one** function? I'm not sure how to do that.

Off the top of my head, I could think of an inequality |A $\cup$ B| $\le$ |A| + |B|. Can you write a formal proof by defining a **one-to-one** function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Find a set $C$ such that $|C|=|A|+|B|$, and define an injective function. One standard way of doing that is to replace $A$ by $A'=\{0\}\times A$ and replace $B$ by $B'=\{1\}\times B$.

Then we have that $|A|=|A'|$ and $|B|=|B'|$, but $A'\cap B'=\varnothing$, in which case $|A'\cup B'|=|A'|+|B'|=|A|+|B|$. Now can you define a function from $A\cup B$ into $A'\cup B'$?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just chose the inequality for illustration purposes. I don't think the injective function is a good way to prove |A $\cup$ B| $\le$ |A| + |B| since A and B could be sets of something unrelated to each other.

Comment: I don't know why elements of sets has to be related somehow.

Comment: Sorry, you're right since we're just connecting A', which we have just predefined to be {0} x A, to A and B' to B, we can find the function pretty easily. But, now I'm thinking isn't the function going to have both one-to-one and onto relationships? Suppose A = {C,D}, B = {E,F}, A' = {(0,C), (0,D)}, B' = {(1,E),(1,F)}. Then A $\cup$ B = {C, D, E, F} and A' $\cup$ B' = {(0,C), (0,D), (1,E), (1,F)} and they are both one-to-one and onto. In which case, we have just proved |A $\cup$ B| = |A' $\cup$ B'| instead of |A $\cup$ B| $\le$ |A' $\cup$ B'|

Comment: If $|A\cap B|=0$, then $|A\cup B|=|A|+|B|$. Try that again with $A=\{x,y,z\}$ and $B=\{x,w,v\}$. You have to decide, will you send $x$ to $(0,x)$ or $(1,x)$? But you can't do both.

Comment: I see, that's because the inclusion-exclusion principle states |A $\cup$ B| = |A| + |B| - |A $\cap$ B|. However, our goal is to find a set C such that $|C| = |A| + |B|$, so that we can define an injective function that maps |A $\cup$ B| to |C| to prove |A $\cup$ B| $\le$ |C|. However, by the inclusion-exclusion principle, we obtain |A| + |B| = |A $\cup$ B| + |A $\cap$ B|. How do we find a single set C, so that we can prove |A $\cup$ B| $\le$ |C| by defining an injective function?

Comment: So now, re-read my answer.